# I can't see an error in my code but the whole javascript portion doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, forms, error-handling, syntax-error

I can't get anything to appear in the drop down tabs. The drop down should be the items in either the subject or username list. However, nothing happens even though I think I have coded it correctly. It gives me this error message: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" I have looked for this extra token but can not seem to find it, please help!

```html
<html>
<body>
<?php
//student interface
$file = fopen("subject.csv","r");
$subjects = fgetcsv($file);
fclose($file);
//puts the csv file provided into a 2d array
$studentTable = array();
if (($handle = fopen("students.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  $studentTable[] = $data;
 }  fclose($handle);
}
//creates list that will store list of girls emails
$usernames = array();
//runs through studentTable and appends emails to toEmail. 
for ($I = 0; $I < sizeof($studentTable); $I++){
       array_push($usernames, $studentTable[$I][0]);
  }  

?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   
// Using PHP implode() function to turn the php list into a javascript list
var subjects = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $subjects) . '"]' ?>; 
var usernames = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $usernames) . '"]' ?>; 
document.write(subjects);
var select = document.getElementById("userN");
for(var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
    var opt = usernames[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    //el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}​
var subchoice = [];
subchoice.push(document.getElementById("choice1"), document.getElementById("choice2"), document.getElementById("choice3"), document.getElementById("choice4"), document.getElementById("choice5"));
for(var x = 0; x < subchoice.length; x++) {
 for(var i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++) {
  var opt = subjects[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  //el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  subchoice[x].appendChild(el);
 }
}​
var six = [];
six = subjects;
six.push("null");
var select = document.getElementById("choice6");
for(var i = 0; i < six.length; i++) {
    var opt = six[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    //el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}​
</script> 
<h2> Select your subjects! </h2>
<form>
<p> Select your name </p>
<select id='userN' name='userN'>
<option>Choose a username</option>
</select>
<p> Select your 1st choice subject </p>
 <select id='choice1' name='choice1'>
 <option>Choose a subject</option>
 </select>
<p> Select your 2nd choice subject </p>
 <select  id='choice2' name='choice2'>
 <option>Choose a subject</option>
 </select>
<p> Select your 3rd choice subject </p>
 <select id='choice3' name='choice3'>
 <option>Choose a subject</option>
 </select>
<p> Select your 4th choice subject </p>
 <select  id='choice4' name='choice4'>
 <option>Choose a subject</option>
 </select>
<p> Select your 5th choice subject </p>
 <select id='choice5' name='choice5' >
 <option>Choose a subject</option>
 </select>
<p> Select your 6th choice subject (none is an option) </p>
 <select id='choice6' name='choice6'>
 <option>Choose a subject</option>
 </select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, this issue has affected the whole js portion of the code. Meaning no commands inside the script tags work which is sad. What could have caused this? My php arrays transfer to javascript appropriately so I know that is not the issue here. Something to do with my select tags.

Comment: At first, take a look at the original source code, which was send from the server, when the page was loaded.  That way you can see what PHP actually wrote to the document. You should try to find an extra `<` from the JS part, because that's what JS is complaining about.